# mongodb 3.2 querying data which has 1000+ column

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

Hello guys i need help about querying big data using mongodb 3.2 which have millions of documents and each documents consist of 1000+ keys, can anyone suggest what method possible to call these big data without having problems which is out of memory

i'ved tried many aggregation functions but none work

Comment: you need to say more about what you have, and what you're expected. Performance and memory footprint can be a huge subject, depending of your needs, existing indexes, hardware ressources, mongod configuration, sharding, etc...

Comment: can you post sample data from your collection and show whats the expected output?